# Necessary and sufficient conditions so that $\lim \inf =\inf \lim $

Tags: calculus, limits

I don't remember the necessary and sufficient conditions (or even if there are any) so that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \inf_{a\in A} f(a,n) =\inf_{a\in A} \lim_{n\to\infty}  f(a,n) $.

Can you give me some pointers?

Thanks

**EDIT**

I know that $\inf_{a\in A} \lim_{n\to\infty}  f(a,n) $ is defined.

I also know that $min_{a\in A} f(n,a)\leq min_{a\in A} f(n+1,a)$ and $f(n,a)\leq 1$ if that of any help.

Comment: It is possible for the left side to be defined when the right is not, but if both are defined I have a feeling they must be equal.

Comment: @Regret Thanks for your comment. Have you an example (or intuition) where the right side is not defined when the left is? I fail to see any ...

Comment: $A=\{0,1\}$ and $f(a,n)=(-1)^{n+a}$ should work.

Comment: @Regret Good one. Thanks. In my case, I'm sure that the right side is defined. I edit the question to give more specificity to my request. Thanks to have pointed out this problem.

Comment: @Reget if $A=\mathbb{N}$ and we define $f(a,\ n)$ to be 0 if $a=n$ and 1 otherwise, then the left side is equal to 0 and the right side is equal to 1.

Comment: Thanks, @Tom. I was thinking too finitely.

Comment: @Tom Do you know of any sufficient condition? your example is very basic (and fulfil my additional assumption if you take 0 if $a\leq n$) and bring me to think that may be there are none ...

Comment: Well, if it is of any help, a sufficient condition would be that for a fixed $a$, $f(a,\ n)$ is non-increasing in $n$. Then $\lim_{n\to\infty}  f(a,\ n) = \inf_{n\in \mathbb{N}} f(a,\ n)$.